# Can two non-abelian groups have an abelian product or coproduct?

Tags: group-theory

It is easy to see that two or more abelian groups must have an abelian product (and coproduct, since these constructions coincide in $\sf Ab$.)

I'm not sure how to proceed with this; I just thought of this and have no hints or anything to follow.

Comment: A product of groups is abelian if and only if all of there components are. This is since two elements commute if and if all of there components commute.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there will always be a monomorphism from $G$ into $G\times H$ and $G\oplus H$. And a subgroup of an abelian group is abelian. So... no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be familiar with products of nonabelian groups, say $G \times H$ is a product, with at least one of the groups not abelian, say $G$ is that group. Well $G$ is a "subgroup" of $G \times H$, and is not abelian, so $G \times H$ can not be abelian.

Under the same conditions, let $G * H$ be the coproduct of $G$ and $H$, so it has the universal property of coproducts. There is an obvious map $i_G:G \to G \times H$, and $H \to G \times H$, so by the universal property there is a unique map $G * H \to G \times H$, which commutes. This map is surjective on $i_G(G)$, and the image of abelian groups is abelian, so $G * H$ can not be abelian.

Comment: You could have instead $1_G: G \to G$, and $H \to G$ the trivial morphism.